# Sum function not working on cells with formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 cells with formula.

A1:

```
=IF(B6>=3.3,"1","0")
```

B1:

```
=IF(C6<7,"0", IF(C6<9,"1",IF(C6>=9,"2")))
```

C1:

```
=IF(D6>85,"1","0")
```

my Cell D1 wants to sum up the 3 cells above.

```
=SUM(A1:C1)
```

but this always returns 0.

but when i do

```
=A1 + B1 + C1
```

it returns me my results

why is this so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your formulae are using text instead of numbers

eg `=IF(B6>=3.3,"1","0")` should perhaps be `=IF(B6>=3.3,1,0)`

=A1 + B1 + C1 forces Excel to convert any numeric text to numeric type

Answer (score 2):

You can encapsulate your calculated cells with VALUE() that needs to be summarized:

A1:

> =**VALUE(** *IF(B6>=3.3,"1","0")* **)**

B1:

> =**VALUE(** *IF(C6<7,"0", IF(C6<9,"1",IF(C6>=9,"2")))* **)**

C1:

> =**VALUE(** *IF(D6>85,"1","0")* **)**

D1:

> =SUM(A1:C1)

This will force your formulae to output a number instead of text, and this can be summarized.

Answer (score 0):

Please note: The real issue is with the IF formulas. When returning a value, it should not be in quotes. The quotes make it text. For example, C1: should be If(D6>85,1,0). Then, Value is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just encapsulate the item in the formula you want to be considered a number. In my case I did not want anything in the calculated cell if there is no result (IF = false) but encapsulating the whole formula resulted in a 0 result. If I make false = "" I get an error. So I just have =IF(test=X,Value(true),"") - X in my case is text but can be a number.

Answer (score 0):

May have happened that you wanted to sum a formula that previously uses iterative computation (*circular reference*). In that case, excel ocasionaly turns this feature **ON/OFF** without any notice. You would need to switch **ON** that function previously.

To do that: `Excel -> Option > Formulas ...>`